# Скриншот области и вывод в QLabel формы PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt, qlabel, cv2, qpixmap

Функция должна делать скриншот области и выводить изображение в `QLabel`, но программа вылетает. Что не так где исправить?

```
def test(self):
    img = pyscreeze.screenshot(region=(0, 0, 200, 200))
    bgr_img = np.array(img)
    rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    qImg = QPixmap(QImage(rgb_img.data, rgb_img.shape[0], rgb_img.shape[1], QImage.Format_RGB888))
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qImg)
    self.image_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
    return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуйста, всегда предоставляйте [**минимально-воспроизводимый пример**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), который демонстрирует проблему.

```
import sys
import pyscreeze                                          # pip install PyScreeze
import numpy as np
import cv2

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
image_label = QLabel()

img = pyscreeze.screenshot(region=(110, 110, 600, 600))
bgr_img = np.array(img)
rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    
qImg = QPixmap(QImage(
    rgb_img.data, rgb_img.shape[0], rgb_img.shape[1], 
    QImage.Format_RGB888)
)
# ??? pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(qImg)                          # ??? 
#image_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
image_label.setPixmap(qImg)                                     # !!!

image_label.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: PyQt6..    вылетает с ошибкой. Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Comment: @Александр чтобы получить реальную ошибку - запустите ваш код в терминале/консоли/CMD

Comment: Все спасибо разобрался. Ошибка в имени объекта.     self.image_label.setPixmap(qImg)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'image_label'

Comment: @Александр пожалуйста. Во втором вопросе тоже самое, если так уберите второй вопрос, если нет - зайте знать об этом.